# SQL Select to return a static list of values?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select, unpivot

Is there a way to perform a select and return a static list? Something like the following:

```
select * from ('CA', 'FB', 'FC')
```

It should return

```
CA
FB
FC
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

If you want each value on a separate row, you can use [table constructor `values()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/table-value-constructor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#c-specifying-multiple-values-as-a-derived-table-in-a-from-clause):

```
select val
from (values ('CA'), ('FB'), ('FC')) as t(val)
```

If you wanted more columns, you would use tuples rather than singletons:

```
select val1, val2
from (values 
    ('CA', 'CB'), 
    ('FA', 'FB'),
    ('FC', 'FD') 
) as t(val1, val2)
```

Comment: If you want a multi-column table, you can also use this syntax (at least in Postgresql): SELECT
  col1, colA
FROM (VALUES
  ('hello', 'world'),
  ('run', 'scream')) AS t(col1, colA)

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps:

```
select 'CA'
union all
select 'FB'
union all
select 'FC'
```